# Pointer trouble creating binary trees

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

I am creating a binary tree from a bitstring in c. ie 1100100 creates a tree:

```
  1
 / \
1   1
```

I decided to use a recursive function to build this tree however i keep getting the error
Debug assertion failed... 
Expression : CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

here is a fragment of my code

```
typedef
struct Node {
  char key;
  struct Node *left;
  struct Node *right; 
} Node;

char string[1000];
int i = 0;

void insertRecursivePreorder(Node **node)
{
    Node* parent = *node;
    if(string[i] == '0')
    {
        parent = NULL;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *newn = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newn->key = string[i];
        parent = newn;
        i++;
        insertRecursivePreorder(&newn->left); //errors occur here
        insertRecursivePreorder(&newn->right); //errors occur here
        free(newn);
        free(parent);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    void printTree(Node* node);
    Node* root = NULL;
    scanf("%s", string);
    insertRecursivePreorder(&root);
    //... do other junk
}
```

i was wondering why this error comes about and what i can do to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: yeap i have, i know where the errors occur but honestly using a recurrsive method means its really hard to debug because there are so many pointers and pointers to pointers etc

Comment: actually, i really want to know why i cannot insert &newn->right into my insertRecursivePreorder function

Comment: "i know where the errors occur" -> so how about giving us the stack trace? Also, have you tried valgrind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is likely to be calling `free` on a pointer twice. In `insertRecursivePreorder`, you set `parent` to `newn`, and then call `free` on both. As an example of this, the following program fails (but works if you comment out one of the `free(..)`s):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  int *a = malloc(sizeof(int)),
      *b = a;
  free(a);
  free(b);
  return 0;
}
```

However, there are several problems with your logic here. You should only call `free` when you have *completely* finished with the pointer, so if you are using your tree later you can't free it as you construct it. You should create a second function, `recursiveDestroyTree`, that goes through and calls `free` on the tree (from the bottom up!).

And, you probably want `*node = newn` rather than `parent = newn`, since the latter is the only one that actually modifies `node`.

(You could also change your function to return a `Node *` pointer, and then just go:

```
root = insertRecursivePreorder();
```

and

```
newn->left = insertRecursivePreorder();
newn->right = insertRecursivePreorder();
```

instead of trying to keep track of pointers to pointers etc.)

(Furthermore, on a stylistic point, using global variables is often bad practice, so you could have your `insertRecursivePreorder` take `int i` and `char * string` parameters and use them instead of global variables.)

Comment: OMG thanks so much!! figured it out!! sorry im only a second year soft eng student :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem was: you were never assigning to the double pointer in 'insertRecursivePreorder', so root always stayed NULL.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef
struct Node {
  char key;
  struct Node *left;
  struct Node *right;
} Node;

        /* slightly changed the syntax for the str
        ** ; now '.' indicates a NULL pointer, values represent themselves.
        */
char *string = "12..3.." ;
/* Removed the global index 'i' */

void printTree(Node* node, int level);
unsigned insertRecursivePreorder(Node **pp, char *str);

unsigned insertRecursivePreorder(Node **pp, char *str)
{
    unsigned pos =1;
    if (!*str) { *pp = NULL; return 0; } /* safeguard for end of string */
    if (*str == '.') { *pp = NULL; return pos; }

    *pp  = malloc(sizeof **pp);
    (*pp)->key = *str;
    pos += insertRecursivePreorder(&(*pp)->left, str+pos);
    pos += insertRecursivePreorder(&(*pp)->right, str+pos);
    return pos;
}

void printTree(Node* node, int level)
{
unsigned pos,len;
len = level> 0 ? level : -level;

    for (pos =0; pos < len; pos++) putchar (' ');
    if (!level) printf ("Root=");
    else if (level<0) printf ("Left=");
    else printf ("Right=");
    if (!node) { printf( "Null\n" ); return; }
    printf("Key=%c\n", node->key );
    printTree(node->left, -(len+1) ) ;
    printTree(node->right, len+1) ;
}

int main(void)
{   
    Node *root = NULL;
    unsigned result = 0;
    result = insertRecursivePreorder(&root, string);
    printf( "Result=%u\n", result);
    printTree(root, 0);
    return 0; printTree(root, 0);
}
```

Output:

```
Result=7
Root=Key=1
 Left=Key=2
  Left=Null
  Right=Null
 Right=Key=3
  Left=Null
  Right=Null
```